# F# - how can I convert an F# function into a System.Delegate using reflection?

Tags: asp.net-core, reflection, f#

Say I have a basic function, like:

`let double x = x * 2`

Since I know the types, I can convert it into a `Func<_,_>` explicitly, which can then be used as a `Delegate`:

`let doubleFuncExplicit = Func<int, int>(double)`

However, when I attempt to do this by using `Activator.CreateInstance()` instead of the constructor, like so:

```
// derive the type for Func<int, int>
let genericType = typeof<Func<obj, obj>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
let specificTypeDef = genericType.MakeGenericType([| typeof<int>; typeof<int> |])
// ...and instantiate it
let doubleFuncReflected =  Activator.CreateInstance(specificTypeDef, [| double |])
```

...I get the following exception on the last line:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Func`2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0007>.$FSI_0007.main@() in C:\dev\2023\MoneyClock2023\src\MoneyClock\MoneyClock.Tests\Scratch.fsx:line 16
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

Am I on the right track? **How can I convert an F# function into a delegate?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work, because when you pass `[| double |]` as arguments to `Activator.CreateInstance`, the `double` function becomes an F# first-class function (a class inherited from generic `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<_, _>` that the runtime has no way of understanding.

I believe you probably need to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`. This takes an object instance and a method you want the delegate to invoke.

The F# first-class function type has an `Invoke` method and so if you take `double` as a value, you can use that as the instance and pick its `Invoke` method. The following works for me:

```
open System

let double x = x * 2
let doubleFuncExplicit = Func<int, int>(double)

let genericType = typeof<Func<obj, obj>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
let specificTypeDef = genericType.MakeGenericType([| typeof<int>; typeof<int> |])
let f = double // To make sure we have the function as a value
let mi = f.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")
let doubleFuncReflected = Delegate.CreateDelegate(specificTypeDef, f, mi) 

// You can cast and invoke the returned delegate
(doubleFuncReflected :?> Func<int, int>).Invoke(123)
```

Comment: more academic than functionally important, when I try to convert `fun () -> "Hello"` to a `Func<string>`, despite that also being explicitly possible (`let helloFuncExplicit = Func<string>(fun () -> "Hello")`), it fails due to parameter count mismatch? I can convert it to a `Func<unit, string>`, but for interop purposes it would be nice to create a delegate requiring no parameters instead of `unit`.

Comment: answering my own question: the best approach I found was just to handle the `unit` single-parameter function as a special (simpler) case, e.g. `if typeof<'a> = typeof<unit> then Func<'b>(fsFunc :> obj :?> unit -> 'b) :> Delegate else (* as above *)`